# AddSingleton - lifetime - does class need to implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, garbage-collection

When using DI for services added using `AddScoped` or `AddSingleton`, does the service need to implement `IDisposable` (even if it is not using any unmanaged resources like files)?

Found below sample from Microsoft Docs:

```
// Services that implement IDisposable:
public class Service1 : IDisposable {}
public class Service2 : IDisposable {}
public class Service3 : IDisposable {}

public interface ISomeService {}
public class SomeServiceImplementation : ISomeService, IDisposable {}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // The container creates the following instances and disposes them automatically:
       services.AddScoped<Service1>();
       services.AddSingleton<Service2>();
       services.AddSingleton<ISomeService>(sp => new SomeServiceImplementation());

    // The container doesn't create the following instances, so it doesn't dispose of
    // the instances automatically:
       services.AddSingleton<Service3>(new Service3());
       services.AddSingleton(new Service3());
}
```

What happens if I have this code:

```
public class Service0  // (doesn't implement Disposable) 

services.AddScoped<Service0>();   // what happens to it when request scope ends? Does it stay on the heap?

services.AddSingleton<Service0>();   // it lives till application dies
services.AddSingleton(new Service0());  // ??
services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<Service0>>((ctx) =>
   {
          return new ConfigureNamedOptions<Service0>(null, (config) =>
   {
// Do something here -- in debug mode it is executing this logic for each request
}}  // it is returning "new Service0" when a request is made. Does it mean for each request it returns new object and keeps in heap memory or returns same previously created object?
```

Comment: That particular Microsoft documentation example simply tries to educate you about the container's behavior when it comes to disposable components. It is not meant to tell you that all components must implement `IDisposable`. On the contrary: having to implement `IDisposable` should be the exception, not the norm.

Answer (score 6):

> does the service need to implement IDisposable(even if it is not using any unmanaged resources like files)

Usually it doesn't, because the primary purpose of `IDisposable` is allow releasing unmanaged resources. However, there is an additional reason for implementing `IDisposable`. The `Dispose()` method is sometimes used as a hook for completing actions started in the constructor. For example, a constructor starts duration measurement, while `Dispose()` stops the measurement and reports the duration to some monitoring mechanism.

#### A little of backgroiund about IDisposable

If an object doesn't implement `IDisposable` it doesn't mean it stays in heap. In fact, the GC doesn't even know what `IDisposable` is. This interface is only a pattern. However, the compiler knows `IDisposable`, and it emits calls to `Dispose()` in the end of `using` statement scope.

In addition, in many cases infrastructure layers or libraries (such as DI in ASP.NET Core) check if an object implements `IDisposable`, and if it does, call `Dispose()` on it.

So the fact that an object implements `IDisposable` doesn't by itself guarantee that `Dispose()` will be called before GC. It depends on the users of the object. To actually ensure `Dispose()` before GC, the full implementation of the disposable pattern includes calling `Dispose()` from the "destructor".

> what happens to it when request scope 
>    ends? stays in heap? what happens to it when request scope 
>    ends?

- `AddScoped<Service0>()`: at the end of the request, the reference to the object is "forgotten" (the GC is free to remove it at any moment). Just prior to forgetting the reference, the object is checked for whether it implements `IDisposable`, and if it does, `Dispose()` will be called on it.
- `AddSingleton<Service0>()`: at the end of the web host lifetime, the reference to the object is "forgotten" (the GC is free to remove it at any moment). Just prior to forgetting the reference, the object is checked for whether it implements `IDisposable`, and if it does, `Dispose()` will be called on it.
- `AddSingleton(new Service0())`: at the end of the web host lifetime, the reference to the object is "forgotten" (the GC is free to remove it at any moment). But since this object was supplied from the outside and not instantiated by the DI, it won't be checked for `IDisposable` and the `Dispose` won't be called.

Comment: Since its missing from your list, providing a factory method that returns an `IDisposable` will also call `Dispose`, even if that factory returns a "static" instance. For example, `services.AddSingleton(_ => new Service0());` and `var s0 = new Service0(); services.AddSingleton(_ => s0);` will both get disposed (if they implement `IDisposable`)

Comment: Question on AddSingleton(new Service0()):  confused on this statement "it won't be checked for IDisposable",  as @pinkflyoedx33 mentioned  if we implement "IDisposable" it will be cleaned, only thing is GC wont trigger auto-clean for this object. correct me if I'm wrong. Another Question services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<Service0>>((ctx) =>   {
          return new ConfigureNamedOptions<Service0>(null, (config) =>
   {// Do something here
}} . what does it mean it returns "new service0" at each new request. I thought it gets created first time and following requests it just ignores.

Comment: in my application "new service0" deals with IConfigurationHost which deals with reading config files which internally triggers physicalfileswatcher changetoken. just wondering if it creates "new service0" for each request will it trigger too many changetokens.

Answer (score 0):

IDisposable is just an interface which give the implementer class the chance to do some cleanup on object destruction , it does not do anything by itself.
DI will destroy the instances depends on their lifetime like scoped , transient , Singleton, will the object exists after destruction on the heap is the Gorbagge Collector's duty to decide .
If you define a new instace inside a Singleton that object will be destroyed with the Singleton instace and due to lifetime of the Singleton which is till the end of the application's lifetime therefore it will follow it's parent's lifetime , except if you do some unmanaged operation there.

Comment: services.AddScoped<someservice>(); when I make a httprequest, in memory dump I can see object count went up, but this count doesn't go down even if I call GC.collect. I thought GC.collect will force to decrease object counter or is it something child object is stopping this object to destroy(I'm also disposing child objects to be on safer side) or its up to GC when to clean it. not sure where I'm going wrong FYI: child object involves EntityFramework context

Comment: What is the scope of the entity framework's db context ?

Comment: my understanding by default DBcontext always works as scoped context  services.AddDbContext<someContext>((options) =>
            {
                var connectionFactory = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetService<IConnectionFactory>();
                options.UseSqlServer(connectionFactory.GetConnectionString("somecdbconnection"));
            });  contextFile has this code   private static Dictionary<Type, List<Tuple<Type, string, string>>> tempdic= new Dictionary<Type, List<Tuple<Type, string, string>>>();
DbSet<someEntity> training{ get; set; }